# Start and end of textpath on path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In my d3.js code, I have created a textpath with some offset. How can I get the start and end position of the textpath specified in terms of path.getPointAtLength?

Comment: That's not a complicated task. However, please add some code to your question, at least the code that create the path and the textpath (with the offset). Do that using the stack snippet.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the encouraging comment! (that‘s what I thought) - I will strip down my my code to the basics and add it here tonight.

Comment: Just tell us this: how are you setting the offset?

Comment: The text is centered on the path by: text-anchor=„middle“ and startoffset=„50px“. That’s really all there is. The path goes from the left border of the svg to the right.. I want an arbitrary text to be placed as textpath and need the start and endpoint for some animation effect.

Comment: Sorry I mean text-anchor=„middle“ and startoffset=„50%“

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't provide your code, I'm going to use [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2565344) from Mike Bostock, setting the text-anchor to `middle` and the offset to `50%`, as you did:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 500);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("id", "curve")
  .attr("d", "M100,200C200,100 300,0 400,100C500,200 600,300 700,200C800,100 900,100 900,100");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("id", "curve-text")
  .append("textPath")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("xlink:href", "#curve")
  .attr("startOffset", "50%")
  .text("We go up and down and up");
```

```css
#curve-text {
  font: 40px sans-serif;
}

#curve {
  stroke: #999;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

To get the start and end points, we need two values: the length of the path and the length of the text:

```
var pathLength = d3.select("path").node().getTotalLength();
var textLength = d3.select("text").node().getComputedTextLength();
```

With those two values we can easily calculate the points. Here, `0.5` is the offset:

```
var startPoint = d3.select("path").node().getPointAtLength(pathLength * .5 - textLength / 2);
var endPoint = d3.select("path").node().getPointAtLength(pathLength * .5 + textLength / 2);
```

Here is the demo with two circles (blue and red) showing the points:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 500);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("id", "curve")
  .attr("d", "M100,200C200,100 300,0 400,100C500,200 600,300 700,200C800,100 900,100 900,100");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("id", "curve-text")
  .append("textPath")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("xlink:href", "#curve")
  .attr("startOffset", "50%")
  .text("We go up and down and up");

var pathLength = d3.select("path").node().getTotalLength();
var textLength = d3.select("text").node().getComputedTextLength();

var startPoint = d3.select("path").node().getPointAtLength(pathLength * .5 - textLength / 2);
svg.append("circle").attr("cx", startPoint.x).attr("cy", startPoint.y).attr("r", 10).attr("fill", "blue").attr("opacity", .6);


var endPoint = d3.select("path").node().getPointAtLength(pathLength * .5 + textLength / 2);
svg.append("circle").attr("cx", endPoint.x).attr("cy", endPoint.y).attr("r", 10).attr("fill", "red").attr("opacity", .6);
```

```css
#curve-text {
  font: 40px sans-serif;
}

#curve {
  stroke: #999;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - looks great. One comment though, With svg 2.0, the reference to the path should be attr(„href“, „#curve“). „Xlink:href“ is deprecated.

Comment: Well, I just copy-pasted from Bostock.